# Need help to draw multiples balls inside a rect on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to draw multiples balls inside a rect. I have a rect and 4 informations. Width and height of the rect.. numbers of balls per line and numbers of lines. That's been said I have to draw, for example, 4 balls at the same line. starting by the corners(That I was able to do) but I can't figure out how to draw more than 2 balls, example: If I have 3 balls, I need to draw 2 in the corners and 1 in the middle, if I have 4 balls... 2 in the corners and 2 in the middle. I had the idea of think about the rect as a matrix but having no luck.. [link to see what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZenGD.png)

Comment: Start coding, share what you could code so far and we will help you if you face any problem, but we can't write code for you.  
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to drawn for example n dragon balls on line then you can divide length with n + 1 to get spacing between center of balls, or if you want different offset on start and end then you would divide (width - 2*offset) / (n - 1).

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="100">
</canvas>

<script>
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    class Rect {
        constructor(x, y, width, heght) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.width = width;
            this.heght = heght;
        }
    }

    class Circle {
        constructor(x, y, radius) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.radius = radius;
        }
    }

    class Scene
    {
        constructor() {
            this.items = [];
        }
        clear() {
            this.items = [];
        }
        add(item) {
            this.items.push(item);
        }
        draw(ctx) {
            for(let item of this.items) {
                if (item instanceof Rect) {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.rect(item.x, item.y, item.width, item.heght);
                    ctx.stroke();
                } else if (item instanceof Circle) {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(item.x, item.y, item.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                    ctx.stroke();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    const scene = new Scene();
    scene.clear();
    scene.add(new Rect(0, 0, 300, 100));

    let n = 5;
    let offset = 30;
    let spacing = ((300 - 2 * offset ) / (n - 1));

    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scene.add(new Circle(i * spacing + offset, 50, 25))
    }
    scene.draw(ctx);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I loved it and i'm using it now... although i'm having trouble trying to positioning the balls inside my draw... see what I got so far and if you have a little more time to give me a hand in this <3 (I need to put the balls inside the third rect only no matter what width or height the user enter)

```
    function draw() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        scene.clear();

        context.beginPath();
        context.strokeRect(zoomedX(0), zoomedY(0), zoomed(width), zoomed(height));
        context.strokeRect(zoomedX(55), zoomedY(55), zoomed(width-10), zoomed(height-10));
        context.strokeRect(zoomedX(60), zoomedY(60), zoomed(width-20), zoomed(height-20));
        context.closePath();

        let radius    = 8;
        let n         = 3;
        let lines     = 3;
        let offset    = 68;
        let offsetY   = 68;
        let spacing   = ((width - 2 * offset ) / (n - 1));
        let spacingY  = ((height - 2 * offset ) / (lines - 1));

        for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for(let j = 0; j < lines ;j++){
                scene.add(new Circle(i * spacing + offset, j * spacingY + offset, radius))
            }
        }

        scene.draw(context);
    }
```

Comment: function zoomedX(number) {
              return Math.floor((number - wx) * scale + sx);
            }

            function zoomedY(number) {
              return Math.floor((number - wy) * scale + sy);
            }

Comment: Hi, you need to take into account position of rectangles, something like:
new Circle( rect.x + i * spacing + offet,  rect.y + y * spacingY + offset, radius), where rect.x, rect.y is position of rectangle you want to center circles in.